# Get association data of the running workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I need to programmatically get `AssociationData` of the running workflow from console application. Now I can only get `AssociationData` of its parent (workflow association at the list).

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp:2200"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            string parentAssociationData =
                web.Lists["TestWorkflow"].GetItemById(1).Workflows[0].
                    ParentAssociation.AssociationData;
        }
    }
```

I need something like this

```
string neededData = item.Workflows[0].AssociationData;
```

because when you start workflow manually and change its settings right before start: `workflow.AssociationData != workflow.ParentAssociation.AssociationData`

For example I can get that data in the custom workflow through the

```
SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();
workflowProperties.AssociationData
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand `AssociationData`. The association data is only entered *once* upon associating the workflow with your list. You said that you are changing the settings **right before start** - in that case you are talking about `InitiationData`!
 [SPWorkflowActivationProperties.InitiationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.initiationdata) will help you:

> --> Gets the initiation data passed to the workflow **instance**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes you are right. How can I get SPWorkflowActivationProperties object using SPWorkflow object?

Comment: I found similar post.

[link](http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--workflow/how-do-i-get-initiationdata-from-a-workflow-that-is-running-44386.shtml)

"otherwise, from a non workflow aspx page, well, you cannot...(unless your workflow stores its initiationData into a custom list or a custom column which cannot be done by OOB workflows)"